# Atomicty of read/write operation over string in c#

Tags: c#, string

when we read string from heap, does that operation is atomic read/write operation?

I am confused here, if i have string like `Hello World` then size of this string is 11 * 2 = 22 bytes so when compiler(86x/64x) read this string it simply cannot read string in one operation so it is not atomic operation.

Or on another way string is read as array of characters and each read/write operation of character is atomic. So does that mean read/write operation on string is atomic.

Comment: Maybe you should give and example (and characters are two bytes in .net)

Comment: it is difficult to give sample example here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning a string reference to another reference *is* an atomic operation because only a pointer is assigned.

For example:

```
string x = "Hello";
string y = x; // This is an atomic operation: Reference assignment.
```

However, copying the contents of a string somewhere (e.g. when making a P/Invoke call) is NOT an atomic operation, as you point out.

Note that because strings are immutable, multithreading issues relating to them being changed do not arise in managed code.